# How to display part of a bitmap transparent

Tags: delphi, bitmap, transparency, delphi-xe

I want to anti-alias some bitmap in Delphi. The file is loaded from file, assigned to an image, processed (`apply_kernel`) and the result is assigned to another image. In Delphi the left/bottom pixel determines the transparent color when `Image.Transparent = True`. I work only with 32 bit bitmaps.

```
dump ('henon.bmp');
Image3.Picture.LoadFromFile ('henon.bmp');
apply_kernel (Image3.Picture.Bitmap, bitmap, kernel);
Image4.Picture.Bitmap := bitmap;
Image4.Picture.Bitmap.SaveToFile ('alias.bmp');
dump ('alias.bmp');
```

This works for the loaded bitmap assigned to Image3, but not for the computed bitmap assigned to Image4. The color of the left/bottom remains unchanged (clWhite). In order to understand what happens I dump the bitmaps to file, each color separately (see dumps below). I did check the transparency of the images, autosize is of, as is center and stretch, the bitmap is 32x32, the images too. I also tried To set `TransparentColor := clWhite`, to no avail. I must make a very stupid mistake but can't find it. Could somebody help me?

**Edit**
Torbins reminded me I had forgotten about the reserved byte. It is set at 128 at some positions, actually exactly the position of the zeroes (see the updated dump). I did several things which in the end resulted in a transparent bitmap:
 - simply zeroed all reserved bytes.
 - a lot more which all did not work until
 - using the assigment works, the Draw does not work strangely enough, the reasoning of Sertac seems sound

Anyhow, the code that works is

```
dump ('henon.bmp');
Image3.Picture.LoadFromFile ('lorenz.bmp');
apply_kernel (Image3.Picture.Bitmap, bitmap, kernel);
Image4.Picture.Bitmap.SetSize (bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
//   Image4.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Draw (0, 0, bitmap); // <== does not work
Image4.Picture.Bitmap := bitmap;                   // <== works  
bitmap.SaveToFile ('alias.bmp');
dump ('alias.bmp');
```

@Sertac, maybe I do something wrong with the Draw?

@Torbins, zeroing all reserved bytes is rather rude, I'll experiment some with your suggestion with the alpha channel

Thanks you all very much!

**henon.bmp:**

```
    Red
        0: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        1: 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        2: 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        3: 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        4: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        5: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        6: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        7: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        8: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        9: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255
       10: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255
       11: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255
       12: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255   0   0 255 255 255
       13: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255   0   0 255 255
       14: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255   0   0 255
       15: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255   0 255   0   0 255
       16: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255   0 255
       17: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255   0   0 255
       18: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255   0   0 255
       19: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255
       20: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255
       21: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255
       22: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255 255
       23: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       24: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       25: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       26: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       27: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       28: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       29: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       30: 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       31: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255

    Green
        0: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        1: 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        2: 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        3: 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        4: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        5: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        6: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        7: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        8: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        9: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255
       10: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255
       11: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255
       12: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255   0   0 255 255 255
       13: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255   0   0 255 255
       14: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255   0   0 255
       15: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255   0 255   0   0 255
       16: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255   0 255
       17: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255   0   0 255
       18: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255   0   0 255
       19: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255
       20: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255
       21: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255
       22: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255 255
       23: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       24: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       25: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       26: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       27: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       28: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       29: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       30: 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       31: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255

    Blue
        0: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        1: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        2: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        3: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        4: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        5: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        6: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        7: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        8: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        9: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       10: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       11: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       12: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       13: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       14: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       15: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       16: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       17: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       18: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       19: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       20: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       21: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       22: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       23: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       24: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       25: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       26: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       27: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       28: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       29: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       30: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       31: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255


reserved
    0:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    1:   0 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    2:   0   0   0 128 128 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    3:   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    4:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128 128 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    5:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    6:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128 128 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    7:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    8:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    9:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128 128 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0
   10:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128   0 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0
   11:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128   0   0 128 128 128   0   0   0
   12:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128   0   0 128 128   0   0   0
   13:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128   0   0   0 128 128   0   0
   14:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128   0   0   0 128 128   0
   15:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128   0 128   0 128 128   0
   16:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128   0   0   0   0 128   0
   17:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128   0   0   0   0 128 128   0
   18:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128   0   0   0   0 128 128   0
   19:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128   0   0   0   0 128 128   0   0
   20:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128   0   0   0   0 128 128   0   0   0
   21:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128   0   0   0   0 128 128   0   0   0   0
   22:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0 128 128   0   0   0   0   0
   23:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   24:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   25:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   26:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   27:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   28:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   29:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   30:   0   0   0   0   0 128 128 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   31: 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

**alias.bmp:**

```
    Red
        0: 194 154 148 106  98  98 123 156 205 238 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        1: 207 177 172 133 114  95 102 121 159 191 216 235 248 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        2: 212 184 179 144 127 110 115 127 150 173 197 214 226 231 237 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        3: 229 216 214 191 168 133 110  98  98 110 127 150 168 185 197 214 231 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        4: 255 248 249 231 214 197 173 150 127 110  98  98  92  92 110 150 185 214 226 237 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        5: 255 255 255 255 249 237 226 214 197 173 150 121  92  69  69  86 110 144 173 197 214 231 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        6: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 237 226 214 185 150 110  86  81  75  69  81 110 150 185 220 243 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        7: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 214 197 173 139  98  69  52  46  69 110 162 202 226 237 249 255 255 255 255 255
        8: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 237 226 202 162 110  69  40  34  52  98 150 179 197 220 243 255 255 255 255
        9: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 243 220 185 144  92  52  40  52  81 110 139 168 202 231 249 255 255
       10: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 202 162 110  75  57  75  86 110 127 156 191 231 248 255
       11: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 243 220 179 139  92  81  92 121 121 121 133 185 229 255
       12: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 220 173 115  86  92 127 139 133 127 156 197 238
       13: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 214 150  98  98 139 162 144 121 127 159 204
       14: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 231 173  98  75 110 168 168 144 121 127 161
       15: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 243 197 115  81 104 162 173 150 110 114 153
       16: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 231 173  98  75 110 179 208 185 133 114 153
       17: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 214 150  98  98 150 208 214 168 121 114 153
       18: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 220 173 115  92 115 179 220 202 156 127 127 161
       19: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 185 144 115 121 162 208 202 168 139 133 159 204
       20: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 237 214 185 144 121 121 162 197 197 168 144 144 168 204 238
       21: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 214 202 191 168 144 144 162 185 197 179 150 144 168 208 242 255
       22: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 220 202 179 150 150 156 168 168 185 197 185 162 156 173 208 243 255 255
       23: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 237 226 220 208 191 162 150 150 173 179 179 173 179 173 173 185 197 220 243 255 255 255
       24: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 243 226 214 202 185 173 173 179 179 173 179 179 173 156 162 185 208 220 231 249 255 255 255 255
       25: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 202 173 162 162 173 179 179 173 179 179 162 150 156 185 208 231 249 255 255 255 255 255 255
       26: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 243 226 197 179 173 173 168 168 168 150 150 162 185 197 202 220 243 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       27: 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 214 197 185 168 156 144 139 139 150 179 202 220 226 237 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       28: 255 255 255 255 249 231 214 202 191 173 162 150 144 150 173 191 202 214 231 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       29: 255 255 255 249 237 208 179 150 150 162 185 197 202 202 214 226 237 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       30: 255 255 255 242 216 172 146 140 172 197 216 223 229 235 248 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       31: 255 255 255 246 230 205 189 180 197 222 246 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255

    Green
        0: 194 154 148 106  98  98 123 156 205 238 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        1: 207 177 172 133 114  95 102 121 159 191 216 235 248 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        2: 212 184 179 144 127 110 115 127 150 173 197 214 226 231 237 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        3: 229 216 214 191 168 133 110  98  98 110 127 150 168 185 197 214 231 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        4: 255 248 249 231 214 197 173 150 127 110  98  98  92  92 110 150 185 214 226 237 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        5: 255 255 255 255 249 237 226 214 197 173 150 121  92  69  69  86 110 144 173 197 214 231 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        6: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 237 226 214 185 150 110  86  81  75  69  81 110 150 185 220 243 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
        7: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 214 197 173 139  98  69  52  46  69 110 162 202 226 237 249 255 255 255 255 255
        8: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 237 226 202 162 110  69  40  34  52  98 150 179 197 220 243 255 255 255 255
        9: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 243 220 185 144  92  52  40  52  81 110 139 168 202 231 249 255 255
       10: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 202 162 110  75  57  75  86 110 127 156 191 231 248 255
       11: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 243 220 179 139  92  81  92 121 121 121 133 185 229 255
       12: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 220 173 115  86  92 127 139 133 127 156 197 238
       13: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 214 150  98  98 139 162 144 121 127 159 204
       14: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 231 173  98  75 110 168 168 144 121 127 161
       15: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 243 197 115  81 104 162 173 150 110 114 153
       16: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 231 173  98  75 110 179 208 185 133 114 153
       17: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 214 150  98  98 150 208 214 168 121 114 153
       18: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 220 173 115  92 115 179 220 202 156 127 127 161
       19: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 185 144 115 121 162 208 202 168 139 133 159 204
       20: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 237 214 185 144 121 121 162 197 197 168 144 144 168 204 238
       21: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 214 202 191 168 144 144 162 185 197 179 150 144 168 208 242 255
       22: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 220 202 179 150 150 156 168 168 185 197 185 162 156 173 208 243 255 255
       23: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 237 226 220 208 191 162 150 150 173 179 179 173 179 173 173 185 197 220 243 255 255 255
       24: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 243 226 214 202 185 173 173 179 179 173 179 179 173 156 162 185 208 220 231 249 255 255 255 255
       25: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 202 173 162 162 173 179 179 173 179 179 162 150 156 185 208 231 249 255 255 255 255 255 255
       26: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 243 226 197 179 173 173 168 168 168 150 150 162 185 197 202 220 243 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       27: 255 255 255 255 255 255 249 231 214 197 185 168 156 144 139 139 150 179 202 220 226 237 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       28: 255 255 255 255 249 231 214 202 191 173 162 150 144 150 173 191 202 214 231 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       29: 255 255 255 249 237 208 179 150 150 162 185 197 202 202 214 226 237 249 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       30: 255 255 255 242 216 172 146 140 172 197 216 223 229 235 248 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
       31: 255 255 255 246 230 205 189 180 197 222 246 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255

    Blue (omitted as it is all 255)
```

Comment: Which version of Delphi do you have?

Comment: @Arnold - Re - question in question: After you call 'SetSize' you have a 32x32 white bitmap. If you end up with an image with white background then the draw is working as expected. If not, dunno, it may be due to alpha channel, I'd try setting the pixel format to 'pf24bit'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to anti-alias some bitmap in Delphi.

If you want to draw with alpha-transparency, then you need to check forth byte (rgbReserved) of your bitmaps. In modern Delphi versions the use of that forth byte is controlled via TBitmap.AlphaFormat. You need to set it to afDefined and that's all. In older Delphi versions you will need to draw bitmaps manually via [AlphaBlend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.
Also for older Delphi versions I have created this unit, maybe it will help you somehow: http://mikolatorbins.narod.ru/AlphaImageUtils.pas (it is free for any use).

Comment: See my update above, this suggestion helped me. Impressive code by the way. What exactly do you use it for?

Comment: I have created it to test drawing on Aero glass in Vista. It can draw png's and bitmaps with forth byte set. Also it can combine two images in to one (useful for buffered drawing).

Answer (score 4):

You have to *draw* the bitmap, assigning won't work. See the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.TBitmap.TransparentColor) for `TransparentColor` for instance:

> Determines which color of the bitmap is to be transparent when the
>   bitmap is drawn.

But then it's likely that you'll still end up with a white background. Here's how it goes: If you use something like `Image4.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(..` the image will be drawn such that pixels having the transparent color in the source image will not be drawn. That is, the background of the target image with those pixels will not be changed. And those unchanged pixels are white (default background color of a new bitmap). So you'll have to use something like this:

```
Image4.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen; // specify your background color
Image4.Picture.Bitmap.SetSize(32, 32);               // now you have a green bitmap
Image4.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bitmap); // draw non-transparent parts over green bg.
```

Comment: Thank you and Glenn1234 for your suggestion. It still does not work so I think it must be in the bitmap. I will do some experiments and get back as soon as I know more. Thanks.

Comment: @Arnold - You're welcome. In case of a possible misunderstanding, the '.Transparentxx' properties have nothing to do with alpha channel.

Comment: I know, as far as I know the left/bottom is some workaround for the fact that the bitmap had no transparency when it was defined.

Answer (score 2):

To borrow from the Delphi help documentation I have here.

```
 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    mybitmap: TBitmap;
  begin
    mybitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      with mybitmap do begin
        LoadFromFile('C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi 3\Images\Splash\256color\factory.bmp');
        Transparent := True;
        TransParentColor := mybitmap.canvas.pixels[25,25];
        Form1.Canvas.Draw(0,0,myBitMap);
        TransparentMode := tmAuto;   // Transparent color now is clDefault =  TColor($20000000);
        Form1.canvas.Draw(250,0,myBitMap);
        end;
    finally
       myBitmap.free;
    end;
end;
```